# Datatables: column search with stripped HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Referencing to the Datatables [API](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html).

I implemented individual column searching and need to extend it:
There is a column which is displaying a button with HTML-Attributes/Classes applied. The Problem: I need to strip HTML in order to search the button's caption only. Any ideas how can I do that?

Here's my code:

```
table().every(function () {
    var that = this;
    $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function (e) {
        if (e.which == 27) {
            $(this).val('');
        }
        if (that.search() !== this.value) {
            that.search(this.value).draw();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide your HTML and explain more in detail what do you need to extract from the `button`'s element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe, you may need to employ external (custom) search function [`$.fn.DataTable.ext.search`](https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/search#Plug-in-structure) in order to look for button texts only (if that's what you're trying to achieve).

You may find the **demo** below:

```js
//Sample source data
const srcData=[
 {title:'apple',cat:'fruit',score:'good'},
 {title:'strawberry',cat:'berry',score:'good'},
 {title:'broccoli',cat:'vegie',score:'bad'},
 {title:'durian',cat:'fruit',score:'bad'}
];
//Global variable for button text custom search
var buttonText = '';
//DataTables initialization
const dataTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
  dom: 't',
  data: srcData,
  columns: [
   {title: 'title', data: 'title'}, 
   {title: 'category', data: 'cat'},
   //render score property as a button
   {title: 'score', data: 'score', render: (data, type, row, meta) => `<button>${data == 'good' ? 'Love it!' : 'Hate it!'}</button>`}
  ],
 });
//Append <tfoot> and searchbars
$('#mytable').append('<tfoot><tr></tr></tfoot>');
dataTable.columns().every(function () {
 $('#mytable tfoot tr').append(`<td><input colindex="${this.index()}"></input></td>`);
});
//Custom search function across button text only
$.fn.DataTable.ext.search.push((settings, row, rowIndex, rowData, counter) => $(dataTable.row(rowIndex).node()).find('td:eq(2) button').text().toLowerCase().includes(buttonText) || buttonText == '');
//Listen for 'keyup' in <tfoot> searchbars
$('#mytable').on('keyup', 'tfoot td input', function () {
 const colindex = $(this).attr('colindex');
 //If it's input in 3-rd column (colindex==2) 
 //simply assign global variabl and re-draw 
 //table to apply custom search
 if (colindex == 2) buttonText = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
 //Otherwise search by corresponding column
 else dataTable.column(colindex).search($(this).val());
 dataTable.draw();
});
```

```css
tfoot td {
  padding-left: 10px !important
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<table id="mytable"></table>
</body>
</html>
```